# I need some kind of decission module in flowground

Tags: flowground, ipaas

I'm trying to send different message cards to multiple teams channels.
I have already created a webhook (telekom/webhook) for this which gives me the right variables via json.
There are four department receiver channels (telekom/rest-api-component) which are also configured to send pre-formatted teams message cards with the variables they have submitted.

Currently this happens to all channels at the same time. In between I would need an "action" in which I can decide which of the channels is served based on the input values. Unfortunately I don't find anything suitable due to the variety of the apis. Do you know how I could realize this ? So something like if value department = Backoffice then (Teams "Account Management") action.

In order to be able to talk with the different applications from Office 365 I wanted to use the Microsoft Graph api which is now available for some time. I couldn't find them in Flowground. Are you planning to include this module ?
For the implementation with Office365 flows this would be absolutely necessary for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the Content-Based-Router: https://doc.flowground.net/guides/content-based-router.html, it is available on the Connector Catalog.

Answer (score 2):

I want to come back to this question: The CBR is a good choice for executing decisions indeed. But is is this the best solution in every situation? I do not think so.

Assume the following task:
Depending on an input parameter `test` you want to fire a request  to different web services (WS1:google.de and WS2:bing.de)

**Solution 1:** You realize the requests with dedicated connectors for WS1 and WS2.
In this case you need the CBR in front of WS1 connector and WS2 connector to decide, what connector has to been used next.
**Solution 2:** You are able to realize both requests with REST-API connector. In this case you can use a JSONATA expression as URL mapping, e.g.
`(test="google") ? "http://google.de" : http://bing.de`
By using JSONATA expressions **every** connector has (limited) capability for executing decisions.

Solution 2 has a big advantage when you are using realtime flows. In this case you are able to reduce the number of connectors they are needed for running the flow and (very important from a cost perspective ) the number of permanently claimed token by this flow.
For reducing the complexity of  JSONATA expressions (e.g. when you add further search engines) and for separation of individual configuration items you can use  the configuration connector (we can discuss this in a separate thread if needed).

Solution 1 is the choice without alternative when you have to decide between different structures/connectors they need to be executed within a flow.